# Improving Query Time for a Job Queue Built on PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using Python + Django (specfically ORM) + PostgreSQL to manage a job queue.

I am running into an issue, basically the jobs are setup as such.

```
ID         STATUS          RESULT
1400       IN_PROGRESS     NULL
...        ...             ...
9999999    SCHEDULED       NULL
```

I have a worker that pulls these jobs off of the Queue, but the query to simply select the latest 'scheduled' job is taking 40seconds +.  How can I improve this speed?

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT "job"."id" FROM "jobs" WHERE "job"."status" = "SCHEDULED" ORDER BY "job"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Python Code:

```
Job.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True).filter(status=Job._SCHEDULED_).first()
```

Comment: Try creating an index on `status` column, if you haven't.

Comment: @AamirAdnan Tried that already to no avail.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Was it a full index on status or a partial index on `status <> completed`? In other words, does your index contain rows with `status = completed`? Why would it? If jobs run once only in their lifetime, then you can easily have millions of finished jobs, which need not to be looked at by your partial index. How about `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_queue`? And with `WHERE status = finished`? And with `WHERE status <> finished`? Did you `[VACUUM] ANALYZE job_queue`? Is `AUTOVACUUM` enabled?

Comment: @flutter Here is the tables DDL:  https://pastebin.com/DaVnk3PU  Hopefully that will help.  I'm not sure if Autovacuum is enabled - it's a postgres server maintained in the cloud.  I would imagine it is on, though.  Anything you could tell me from the table?

Comment: You only answered one of the many questions i asked. Therefore, here is an answer in response to what we both know. What about `CREATE INDEX ON main_keywordjob (status) WHERE status = 'IN_PROGRESS' OR status = 'SCHEDULED'` hm? Then `ANALYZE` to gather statistics and run the query. Post the runtime before and after. Answer the other questions. No input, no output. Your problem is described in bad shape. Consider that the round-trip-time is sometimes measured in days on StackOverflow and your question is old, which means not a lot of people read it. What you don't write, we cannot consider.

Comment: Also what is your `EXPLAIN [ANALYZE]` for your `SELECT` returning as the execution plan? Do you post it?

Comment: Simply because an RDBMS isn't suitable for use as a Queue!! what you should be using is something specifically designed to act like a queue. Redis comes to mind

Comment: @flutter Here is the query plan:  https://pastebin.com/gCGZMjyz . I am using Django's ORM, which only supports indexing entire fields, so I cannot do your other recommendations yet.

Comment: @dmcmulle And why does Django support [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/)? As the programmer, you are the boss of the sourcecode, not the Django framework. Also, which PostgreSQL version? Are partial indexes even available? From your posted Query-Plan: the index scan takes 60 seconds already. Go for partial index. Use raw SQL in Django, if you must. Caveat SQL injections. Also, more info required. How many rows are in the table? Which distinct status? How many rows per status?

Comment: Why is it necessary to keep the data in this table in the first place? Can't you delete old data from it? Less data means faster queries. Is this data only required as temporary data for some running processes on the database, which could be removed after these are finished and persisted? Is the data kept to insure stored partial process results against database outages? What would a rollback and restart in a transaction cost in the event of a database outage?